# оставить в строках только по одной ячейке, соответствующей условию

Tags: r

по мотивам этого вопроса: [замена цикла for на функцию семейства apply в R](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1016144/178576)
 (там, конечно, и вопрос плохо составлен, и упомянутая реализация просто ужасна, но мне стал интересен один частный момент, который и выношу отдельным вопросом).

---

вот есть у нас таблица, и надо нам удалить в каждой строке все ячейки, которые не соответствуют некому условию, да и из тех, что соответствуют — оставить только одну (например самую левую). а если таковых ячеек нет — то и строку удалить полностью.

ну и для пущей сложности — значения в самом первом столбце проверять не надо, и удалять не надо. то есть, должна остаться таблица с двумя столбцами.

пример исходной таблицы:

```
set.seed(42)
cbind(letters[1:5], matrix(sapply(sample(5:10,20,replace=T),\
  function(x) paste0(sample(letters,x),collapse="")),ncol=4))
#      [,1] [,2]         [,3]        [,4]         [,5]        
# [1,] "a"  "xdzvbkhrio" "ovegszxa"  "fjwxqpk"    "clsqrdxfzm"
# [2,] "b"  "tujparvdqk" "dflepahju" "apurjlkzg"  "itjprdacmw"
# [3,] "c"  "jkawzu"     "pdior"     "puijmvohqr" "opemd"     
# [4,] "d"  "xpzohvuwa"  "ofcbgzad"  "gsvnwt"     "lhceqiu"   
# [5,] "e"  "tqeglozu"   "yxrhlpmvd" "wotcqnz"    "mkdsnqpr"
```

а в качестве условия, которому должна соответствовать ячейка, пусть будет наличие подстроки `'m'` (встречается почти в каждой строке, да ещё и не по разу).

т.е., в результате надо получить такую таблицу:

```
#      [,1] [,2]        
# [1,] "a"  "clsqrdxfzm"
# [2,] "b"  "itjprdacmw"
# [3,] "c"  "puijmvohqr"
# [4,] "e"  "yxrhlpmvd"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пусть таблица хранится в переменной `m`.

для начала применим к ней (построчно) `grepl()`, сразу возвращая только первую из найденных ячеек (если таковых больше нуля) либо `NA` (если ячеек не нашлось):

```
apply(m[, -1], 1, function(r) {g<-grepl('m', r); if(any(g)) {r[g][1]} else NA})
# [1] "clsqrdxfzm" "itjprdacmw" "puijmvohqr" NA           "yxrhlpmvd"
```

теперь функцией `cbind()` прицепим к этому вектору (как столбцу) первый столбец исходной таблицы:

```
cbind(m[, 1], apply(m[, -1], 1, function(r) {g<-grepl('m', r); if(any(g)) {r[g][1]} else NA}))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "a"  "clsqrdxfzm"
# [2,] "b"  "itjprdacmw"
# [3,] "c"  "puijmvohqr"
# [4,] "d"  NA
# [5,] "e"  "yxrhlpmvd"
```

почти то, что надо! осталось только удалить строки, где во втором столбце нет значений. поможет в этом функция `is.na()`:

```
t <- cbind(m[, 1], apply(m[, -1], 1, function(r) {g<-grepl('m', r); if(any(g)) {r[g][1]} else NA}))
t[ ! is.na(t[, 2]), ]
#      [,1] [,2]        
# [1,] "a"  "clsqrdxfzm"
# [2,] "b"  "itjprdacmw"
# [3,] "c"  "puijmvohqr"
# [4,] "e"  "yxrhlpmvd"
```